# Can't access admin: "Not Acceptable"

Tags: network-admin

Today I tried to access the admin panel for a basic Wordpress site. It has no plugins, and uses the default theme. I haven't modified any files. Any admin url returns an HTTP 406 "Not Acceptable". What's going on?

Comment: Is there any .htaccess in /wp-admin? edit : 406 happens when the server cannot respond with the accept-header specified in the request.

Answer (score 1):

I found this which might solve your problem:

```
<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>
```

This code goes in a file called `.htaccess` and must be uploaded in `/wp-admin` directory. This will disable `mod_security` which is a module in Apache2 activated by default but it can be problematic.

**EDIT:** @Rarst is right. It is just to see if the problem is here. You'd better not to leave this in `/wp-admin` directory after testing.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to ask hosting support to tweak mod_security rules, rather than trying to completely disable it.

Comment: If it is a problem with `mod_security` you can use `SecRuleRemoveById` to remove the rules that are causing the issue. I wrote a blog post about it ages ago http://www.pablumfication.co.uk/2010/02/05/wordpress-apache-mod_security-part-01/ but not sure how valid it is with the current version of `mod_security` and current version of WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem this morning on ALL the sites hosted with the hosting company I use. Turned out that the hosting company was under a massive attack of some kind, and they were disabling all access for a little while until they could mitigate the issue. So, if someone else stumbles upon this issue and the above solution doesn't work, that could be another answer.

Answer (score -1):

My solution is,m let your host provider know, they'll ask for your IP address, they will clear this address and all is fine again.